# React ReferenceError: document is not defined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, isomorphic-javascript

I'm trying to render the following component on the server side as part of a universal/isomorphic app:

```
import React, { PropTypes, Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import ImmutablePropTypes from 'react-immutable-proptypes';
import { GridLoader } from 'halogen';
import PostListItem from '../../components/PostListItem/PostListItem';
import { primary as color } from '../../colors';
import { changeSelectedPost, deletePostRequest } from '../../redux/modules/post';

export default connect()(class PostListView extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    posts: ImmutablePropTypes.listOf(ImmutablePropTypes.contains({
      name: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
      title: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
      content: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
      slug: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
      id: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    })).isRequired,
    loading: PropTypes.boolean.isRequired,
    dispatch: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  }

  handleClick(post) {
    this.props.dispatch(changeSelectedPost(post));
  }

  handleDelete(post) {
    if (confirm('Do you want to delete this post')) { // eslint-disable-line
      this.props.dispatch(deletePostRequest(post));
    }
  }

  render() {
    if (typeof window !== 'undefined' && this.props.loading) {
      return (
        <div className="container">
          <GridLoader color={color} />
        </div>
      );
    }
    return (
      <div className="listView">
        {
          this.props.posts.toSeq().map((post, i, arr) => (
            <PostListItem
              post={post}
              key={i}
              onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this, post)}
              onDelete={this.handleDelete.bind(this, post)}
            />
          ))
        }
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

but I receive the error:

```
module.exports = document.createElement('div').style;
             ^

ReferenceError: document is not defined
```

Adding the if block seems to have tripped up the app (the app rendered perfectly before, both server and client side). I'm most likely missing something quite obvious, knowing my track record :P. Any suggestions? :)

UPDATE: File that handles server-side rendering and the rest of the app on the server side:

```
// server/server.js
'use-strict';

import path from 'path';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import Express from 'express';
import React from 'react';
import webpack from 'webpack';
import { fromJS } from 'immutable';
import webpackDevMiddleware from 'webpack-dev-middleware';
import webpackHotMiddleware from 'webpack-hot-middleware';
import { match, RouterContext } from 'react-router';
import { Model } from 'objection';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { renderToString } from 'react-dom/server';
import config from '../webpack.config.dev';
import routes from '../shared/routes';
import configureStore from '../shared/redux/configureStore';
import assets from './assets';
import db from './db';
import posts from './routes/post.routes';
import Post from './models/post';
import serverConfig from './serverConfig';

// Initialize the Express App
const app = new Express();

Model.knex(db);

if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
  const compiler = webpack(config);
  app.use(webpackDevMiddleware(compiler, { noInfo: true, publicPath: config.output.publicPath }));
  app.use(webpackHotMiddleware(compiler));
}

// Apply body Parser and server public assets and routes
app.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: '20mb' }));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ limit: '20mb', extended: false }));

if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
  app.use(Express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, '../static')));
}

function getFilename() {
  if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
    return '"/dist/bundle.js"';
  }
  return `"/dist/${assets}"`;
}
app.use('/api', posts);

// Render Initial HTML
const renderFullPage = (html, initState, jsFile) => {
  return `
    <!doctype html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles/normalize.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles/skeleton.css">
        <title>CeresShop</title>
      </head>
        <div id="root">${html}</div>
        <script>
          window.__INITIAL_STATE__ = ${JSON.stringify(initState)};
        </script>
        <script src=${jsFile}></script>
      </body>
    </html>
  `;
};

// Server Side Rendering based on routes matched by React-router.
app.use((req, res) => {
  match({ routes, location: req.url }, (err, redirectLocation, renderProps) => {
    if (err) {
      return res.status(500).end('Internal server error');
    }

    if (!renderProps) {
      return res.status(404).end('Not found!');
    }
    const initialState = fromJS({
      postReducer: {
        posts: [],
        post: {},
        loading: false,
      },
      route: {
        locationBeforeTransitions: null,
      },
    });

    async function loadData() {
      if (req.url.includes('post')) {
        try {
          const newSlug = req.url.substring(5).split('-');
          const newId = newSlug[newSlug.length - 1];
          const newPost = await Post.query().where('id', newId);
          const toBeProcessed = JSON.stringify(newPost[0]);
          return initialState.setIn(['postReducer', 'post'], fromJS(JSON.parse(toBeProcessed)));
        } catch (error) {
          console.log(error);
          return initialState;
        }
      }
      try {
        const newPosts = await Post.query();
        newPosts.sort((a, b) => b.dateadded - a.dateadded);
        const toBeProcessed = JSON.stringify(newPosts);
        return initialState.setIn(['postReducer', 'posts'], fromJS(JSON.parse(toBeProcessed)));
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        return initialState;
      }
    }

    loadData().then((currentState) => {
      const store = configureStore(currentState);
      const createElement = (Component, props) => (
        <Component
          {...props}
          radiumConfig={{ userAgent: req.headers['user-agent'] }}
        />
      );
      const initialView = renderToString(
        <Provider store={store}>
          <RouterContext {...renderProps} createElement={createElement} />
        </Provider>
      );
      const finalState = store.getState().toJS();

      res.status(200).end(renderFullPage(initialView, finalState, getFilename()));
    }).catch(err1 => {
      console.log(err1);
      res.end(renderFullPage(`Error: ${err1}`, {}, getFilename()));
    });
  });
});

// start app
app.listen(serverConfig.port, (error) => {
  if (!error) {
    console.log(`DAT SERVER is running on port: ${serverConfig.port}!`); // eslint-disable-line
  }
});

export default app;
```

Comment: It seems the problem is in some other imported file, Maybe PostListItem

Comment: please show us the file in which the generated server side react string is being passed into the view. also i dont think that document. is a valid expression on the server since there is no document on the server. (same with window..)

Comment: AFAIK, `document` does not exist in a NodeJS runtime environment.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a component that is being rendered server-side that requires another component which will only will be rendered in the client, it will still attempt to export that module on the server. You can either check if `document` exists, or require the module inline.

```
module.exports = typeof document !== 'undefined' ? document.createElement('div').style : null

// or

componentDidMount() {
  // this is only called in the client
  require('./clientComponent')
}
```